# Android - Reading ID3 tags from mp3 stream

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, id3

I'm streaming an mp3 file using `MediaPlayer`

```
mp.setDataSource(myContext, Uri.parse("http://my_song.mp3"));  
mp.prepareAsync();  
mp.setOnPreparedListener(mpOnPreparedListener);  
mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mpOnBufferingUpdateListener);
```

Any idea about how I can read the ID3 tags from this stream using android API or any alternative methods?

Comment: I have no Android experience, but since no one else is answering, have you checked this [link](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=12296)? Also there is another question in SO about ID3 tags in Java (not Android though) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147/i-need-an-id3-tag-reader-library-for-java-preferably-a-fast-one). I hope they help.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all of this using **MediaMetadataRetriever**

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(filePath);   

String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
```

you can get all other tags by using this class.
I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

this is a opensouce project maybe can help you,http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/index.jsp

Jaudiotagger is not the only Java tagging library available, but does have some key benefits you might like to consider in evaluating a library to use

Provide a generic interface for the most popular thirty attributes for all the fully supported formats
Supports reading and writing of mp4,m4a and mp4p (protected) files, including multiple images and reverse dns fields
Supports Multiple Page Ogg Vorbis Comments
Supports MP3 ID3v1,ID3v11, ID3v2.2, v2.3 and v2.4 are transparently
Allows easy conversion between ID3 tag versions
Supports Flac, including embedded and linked image support
Provides proper object representations of most fields, rather than a simple byte representation
Fully supports Unicode Text Encoding
Is being actively developed and supported
Uses an automatic testsuite to ensure code compatibility betweens versions
Uses a Code Coverage tool to ensure code is actually being tested
Is being used by a number of applications